# Create Products with nested attributes

Tags: attributes, attribute-set

Is it possible to create products with nested attributes in Magento? If yes, how can that be achieved?

Comment: what is mean by nested

Comment: Its like I want to create product called IPhone. Then it can have custom attributes like: OS -> (System, CPU, GPU), Memory ->(RAM,STORAGE etc)

Comment: how you have created products?

Comment: Look at Bundle Products

Comment: I just did it the usual Magento way. If you could be  be a little specific regarding your question I could provide you with more information

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/aoepeople/magento-product-types-demystified or http://www.customerparadigm.com/six-types-of-magento-product-types/ or http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-bundle-product-type-part-1/

Comment: I voted to close, but maybe duplicate is better -> http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37625/bundle-vs-group-product

Answer (score 5):

Use attribute-sets and attribute-groups.

Product: iPhone
Attribute-Set: Smartphone (or mobile phone, as you like to call it).
The attribute-set "Smartphone" contains multiple attribute-groups, such as:

- memory
- operating system

Within the attribute-groups, you can add your attributes:

memory

- RAM
- Storage

OS

- System
- CPU
- GPU

[image: Attribute-Set "Smartphone]